# How to guarantee message queue/order in Erlang?

Tags: erlang

If one server receives multiple requests from one process by using pid ! Msg, but the process time for each request is different, then how to guarantee the sender receives the reply in order?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the Erlang FAQ](http://erlang.org/faq/academic.html#idp33041872):

> ## 10.8  Is the order of message reception guaranteed?
>
> Yes, but only within one process.
>
> If there is a live process and you send it message A and then message B, it's guaranteed that if message B arrived, message A arrived before it.
>
> On the other hand, imagine processes P, Q and R. P sends message A to Q, and then message B to R. There is no guarantee that A arrives before B. (Distributed Erlang would have a pretty tough time if this was required!)

That is, if the server processes the requests in the order they arrive, and sends the responses in the order the requests were processed, then the sender will receive the responses in order.

Answer (score 0):

the Erlang **receive** clause can do pattern matching. So what you can do is create a reference for each message that you want to receive and then pattern match on that reference.

Check out this [gist](https://github.com/tafsiri/7languages/blob/master/erlang/pmap.erl) if you look at line 26 you will see that the receive clause is waiting for a message with a specific pid. In this case the messages will arrive in an arbitrary order but by virtue of this receive, they will be put into order.